# VBA transposing code needs to maintain original formatting (font size, centering, etc) in results column

Tags: vba

The VBA code below works great, but the results placed in Column E needs to keep the original source data formatting such as font type and size, cell centering, etc. How would you modify the VBA code below to do this?

VBA code to transpose multiple rows of given range to a single blank column E:

```
Sub RangeToColumn()
Dim varray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    k = 1
    
    varray = Range("A1:D4").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(varray, 2)
            Cells(k, 5).Value = varray(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        Next
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I need this code to create parts inventory labels. The data is imported into Excel in rows, but the label printer only uses one column). The code listed in this thread works great but doesn't copy the font style etc over to Column E which will be printed. Each printed line (Row) in Column E may use a different font size or other.

Thanks for suggestions.

GrievousAngel

Comment: When you convert a range to an array you are just taking the data within the range, formatting and the like are not part of the array. EvR's post below will solve your problem as it will copy and past the cells including their formatting. If your two ranges are both contigous you can probably cut down on some of the looping.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste cell by cell:

```
Sub RangeToColumn()
    Dim k As Long, cl As Range
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        k = 1
        For Each cl In Range("A1:D4")
            cl.Copy
            Cells(k, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
            k = k + 1
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```